# JS document.write function and print character ^

Tags: javascript, escaping, document.write

I'm inserting some html code thanks to the `document.write` function to have the same headers and menus on all my pages. I'm putting a simple reference to a javascript file that contains the `document.write` function and the relevant html code for these sections of my page.

In the menu section triggered by a js script, I have links pointing to several pages. I prepared these links and there are working fine in a html document. One of them has the following character string in it: `"^SESSIONID^"`. It is a dynamic link that I'm compelled to use it as it is part of another program I'm using and that I cannot avoid. The link is embedded within the `document.write` statement of the js script.

My problem is that the `"^"` is rendered by a `"%5E"` and I cannot figure out what to put instead of it to get `"^"` in my document. I tried to put `"%5E"` put I still ended with that same expression.

Here is the code on the page
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://icjap12/menu_EN.js"> </script>`

Here is the relevant part of the code in the js file
`document.write('<a href="^SESSID^/Bibliographie_recherche_BoC_ToC.htm?GET" target="_self"></a>')`

Comment: You mean you're writing a `href` of a link and when you follow that it gets urlencoded? There's nothing wrong with that, and nothing you can do about it.

Comment: "*using document.write to have the same headers and menus on all my pages*" - don't do that!!! Use serverside processing ftw.

Comment: Notice that the `^` *is* in the document (check the DOM inspector). Only when you follow the link it will get percent-encoded. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asqyn/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `&circ;` which is the HTML code for a circumflex character.

Comment: `&circ;` is not the exact circumflex character I needed, but thanks to your comment I got to the `&#94;` and `&#x5e;`, which are the right ones.But I still have the same problem: either `^`, `&#94;` or `&#x5e;`are rendered by a `%5E`.

Comment: Yes, as others have said you're getting a URL encoded result. "^" is not a valid character in a HTTP URI, so it is being converted to %5E.